# Stop regex capturing after double spaces

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the content of a string up to the occurrence of a double space (ignoring the case when the double space is after the autor/name identifier) or any other character different than A-Z or a single blank space, until the moment I came up with the following regular expression, although the \S does match anything except a blank space.

```
(AUTOR|NAME):?([A-Z ]\S)+


AUTOR:  LEANDRO LUCIANI  TAVARES -- This should match up to 'AUTOR:  LEANDRO LUCIANI'

AUTOR LEANDRO LUCIANI \TAVARES -- This should match up to 'AUTOR LEANDRO LUCIANI' discarding anything after the backslash

AUTOR       LEANDRO TAVARES -- This should match up to 'AUTOR       LEANDRO TAVARES'
```

Edit:

I am trying to run it on C# so it must be compatible with the .NET implementation of regular expressions.

Thanks in advance,
Leandro Tavares

Comment: *"up to the occurrence of a double space or **any other character**"*, what other characters specifically, backslash or all non alphanumeric characters? I mean, *all* characters includes [a-z].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably something like that:

```
(AUTOR|NAME)[\s:]\s*([A-Z]+( [A-Z]+)*)
```

Comment: @DougLuce: No this will work any number of whitespaces (except for consecutive whitespaces that are obviously not allowed).

Answer (score 1):

This PCRE works for me:

```
/(AUTOR|NAME):?\s*([A-Z ]+?)(?:  | \\|\\|$)/
```

Comment: I have a very shallow knowledge on regular expressions, so a PCRE expression above won't work on C#, as an example, am I right? I've did a test on regexpal and the second test case still matches the backslash.

Comment: What happens when you change the last ?: to a ?= as in `/(AUTOR|NAME):?\s*([A-Z ]+?)(?=  | \\|\\|$)/`

Comment: It seems to work perfectly on regexpal but when I run it on C# it only matches 'AUTOR: LEANDRO' as an example